# Clicking on a link inside a webview that will trigger a native iOS screen (with params passed from the webview)

Tags: ios, html, cordova, sencha-touch-2, appcelerator

Looking at the Facebook iOS app, one can see that when in the feed (for example), clicking on comment will pop a native iOS dialog, as well as clicking on a photo, will also pop a native iOS screen just for that purpose.
Or clicking on Comments will load a different iOS screen for that.

I'm working on an hybrid iOS app (html5 + obj-c) and would love for this kind of functionality. 
I've checked:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_phone_web-based_application_framework

But can't tell which is the best suited. 
For example, phonegap is very very popular, but not sure if this kind implementation with it (the "native bridge") is something possible. Even if so, if it will require me to handle a major learning curve (it's syntax and writing a special plugin).
What would you have done? 
Which FW is the most appropriate.
I don't use ANY system functionality such as camera / file system / etc.. the phonegap offers except for that native bridge, so think about frame work size wise and that is the ONLY part i need.
That being said , the app isn't to be 100% phonegap or 100% native.

I presume sencha touch 2 is out of the question for this requirement goals

Comment: Could you please describe what you mean by "native iOS screen"? (I don't know iOS programming) It seems to me that what you want can be done just as well with pure web technology and Sencha Touch 2 would certainly work for it.

Comment: Sure.
Sencha Touch provides a JS framework for the web which gives the looks and (delayed) feel of a mobile device.
A native app is an app created using obj-c (iOS), it's behavior is a lot smoother, among other benefits.

Phonegap is a framework that allows you to write web applications and is written for MOST major mobile devices to allow you USE the OS of the mobile device. It Uses the Webview (native iOS control) for this purpose and "Native Bridge" - http://nullisnotanobject.com/phonegap-native-bridge

I'm not sure if clutch.io is the thing i'm looking for

Comment: I know Sencha Touch 2 and Phonegap reasonably well :) . And having used them, I must say that Sencha Touch 2 performance on iOS is pretty darned smooth and good. You should try out some of the examples on any iDevices you have.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware vaguely of how Phonegap works and the native bridge etc. Just wondering why you feel it's not suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, using a custom protocol.

In your html, declare your JS calling function:

```
function callIt(paramText) {
    var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", "my-protocol://" + paramText.replace(/ /gi,'%20'));
    document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    iframe = null;
}
```

On iOS, you will intercept the call using in your webView delegate method webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:

Check if the request has your "my-protocol:" prefix. In this case, extract your parameter from the request using the example "://" separator (you can also use any separator that you wish), and return NO.

Comment: Thanks, would like to hear your take + implementation on this.

Comment: Great answer lead me to 
http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/

Answer (score 0):

**using only sencha framework** you can make custom url scheme calls from your javascript code

for example :

```
window.location='test://'+parameters;
```

in native part you have to write your protocol handler
when a call to this custom url is made, the handler will execute corresponding functions on your native part.

now in opposite direction let's say now you want to pass from native ios to sencha, you can save your data in a javascript file and use it in sencha part, you can call functions in javascript from your native code.

**you don't need to use phoneGap** since you have access to all native framework